# Reshape and animate a list of points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data, visualization

I have a very big list of numbers in a file. They represent locations of pool balls on board over time while they move.

There are $N$ balls, and the points are arrenged such that every $N$ terms on the list are the positions balls at a certain time.

For example, for 2 balls the list:

```
1 1 1 2 1 1.5 1 2 1 2 1 2.5
```

Means that the positions of the balls are:

```
t=t1: ball 1 = {1,1}; ball 2 = {1,2}
t=t2: ball 1 = {1,1.5}; ball 2 = {1,2}
t=t3: ball 1 = {1,2}; ball 2 = {1,2.5}
```

I want to visualize this list on wolfram mathematica. My question is, what is the most efficient way to do it?

(Of course, my list is a lot bigger then the example list with a lot more points. That means, efficiency is critical for me.)

Previously, I used to get the points as a list into Mathematica:

```
pos := ReadList["LOCATION OF THE FILE", {Number, Number}]
```

and then used Graphics to show each time 2 points of the list:

```
numberOfBalls := N;
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  Dynamic[Table[
    {Hue[(2 - k)/numberOfBalls], EdgeForm[Thick], 
     Disk[Reverse[pos[[m + k]]], 0.0265], Black, 
     Text[Reverse[pos[[m + k]]], {0, 0.06} + Reverse[pos[[m + k]]]]}
    , {k, 0, numberOfBalls - 1}]]
  ]
 , {m, 1, Length[pos] - 1, numberOfBalls}]
```

But I'm sure that there is a better and more efficient way to do this.

The link to the list is here: (With 3 balls)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tuqt-3uxOPpgQxSVxnh5ldf_-_mgd7j9/view?usp=sharing

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Partition`:

```
data = First@Import["~/Downloads/wolfram.txt", "Table"];
numberOfBalls = 3;
pos = Partition[Partition[data, 2], numberOfBalls];
Animate[ListPlot[pos[[i]], PlotRange -> {{-.7, .7}, {-1.5, 1.5}}], 
         {i, 1, Length@pos, 1}]
```

For a nice animation, you'd have to take into account the balls diameters, but that's another problem.

**Edit** Using `Graphics` instead of `ListPlot` for more efficiency:

```
Animate[Graphics[Point @ pos[[i]], PlotRange -> {{-.7, .7}, {-1.5, 1.5}}], 
          {i, 1, Length@pos, 1}]
```

Comment: Well that worked like magic! Thanks!

Comment: I would use Graphics directly, avoid the overhead of ListPlot.

Comment: @CarlWoll I read in a recent answer you wrote that Graphics was faster. When would you use ListPlot then? When you want to manage different curve styles, etc.?

Comment: Yes, `ListPlot` is useful for those kinds of things, as well as some others like `Filling`. Note that `Point` supports multiple points, so using `Point[pos[[i]]]` is also possible, and faster if there are a lot of points.

Comment: As Carl says, if you don't need the fancy bits like filling, custom symbols for the points, or automagically removing `Missing[]` entries, then `Graphics[]` has way less overhead than `ListPlot[]`.